# Pyhton quick_sort

Tags: python, quicksort

this is the algorithm for quick sort that we learned the other day at class:

```
def Partition(A, l, r):
    x = A[l]
    i = l + 1  # 
    j = r
    while True:
        while A[i] < x and i < j:
            i += 1
        while A[j] > x and j > i:
            j -= 1
        if i < j:
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
        else:  # When i == j
            A[l], A[i - 1] = A[i - 1], A[l] # Need to check this
            return i - 1


def Quick_sort(A, l, r):
    if l < r:
        P = Partition(A, l, r)
        Quick_sort(A, l, P - 1)
        Quick_sort(A, P + 1, r)
```

but when I try to run the code for the following list:
`C = [40, 10, 30, 20]`
the sorting is not working as it should and I get the wrong output:
`C = [30, 10, 40, 20]`
while the right one should be:
`C = [10, 20, 30, 40]`

I'm pretty sure the problem is with the swap when i == j,
at first I changed it to swap A[i] with A[i-1] and later on I also tried A[0] with A[i-1] but it didn't work

Tried to change the statement of when i == j to swap with the pivot element

Answer (score 0):

On that last swap between A[i-1] and A[l], when all the values are smaller than x, you should not be moving the pivot value.

Actually, you don't need to have that extra logic in the partition function, just include all the indexes and let the swapping move the pivot along with the rest.  There is no need for an exception:

```
def Partition(A, i, j):
    x = A[i]
    while True:
        while A[i] < x and i < j:
            i += 1
        while A[j] > x and j > i:
            j -= 1
        if i < j:
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
        else:
            return i - 1
```